# Let $L$ be the distance between two parallel normals of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, $a>b$, then find maximum value of $L$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

Let the equation of normal be 
$$ax\sec t -by\csc t=a^2-b^2$$

Let the parameters of the two normals be $t$ and $r$

Their slopes are equal 
$$\frac{\sec t}{\csc t}=\frac{\sec r}{\csc r}$$

$$\sin t \cos r-\cos t \sin r=0$$

$$t-r=n\pi$$
Let $n=1$

$$t-r=\pi$$
$$t=\pi +r$$

So the first equation becomes 
$$ax\sec r -by\csc r =b^2-a^2$$

The distance between two parallel lines is 
$$\frac{|a^2-b^2+b^2+a^2|}{\sqrt{ a^2\sec ^2r+b^2\csc^2 r}}$$

To  minimise the denominator , differentiating wrt $r$

$$2a^2\sec^2r\tan r-2b^2\csc^2r\cot r=0$$

$$\tan ^2r=\frac ab$$

Then $$L =\frac{2a^2}{a+b}$$

The given answer is $2(a-b)$, but I am unable to find what is wrong in my computation.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan yes

Comment: Sin't the parametric form for a normal to an ellipse $\frac{x\sec\theta}{a} - \frac{y\tan\theta}{b} = 1$?

Comment: What about $r=0$ or $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$? I think this cases are not covered as $1/\sin r$ and $1/\cos r$ are not defined there. @Aditya

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I think the form is wrong, checked it on google

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin they aren’t defined. What are you implying?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I think my form is right. The one you gave is for tangent of hyperbola

Comment: Right, my bad. That's fine\

Comment: Isn't the numerator $|a^2-b^2+b^2-a^2|=0$? But maybe just a typo. Anyway I don't see how to get $2(a-b)$ from [$a^2\sec^2\left(\arctan\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)+b^2\csc^2\left(\arctan\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)=\dfrac{(a + b)^2 (a^2 - a b + b^2)}{a b}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%5E2%2Fcos%5E2%28atan%28sqrt%28a%2Fb%29%29%29%29%2B%28b%5E2%2Fsin%5E2%28atan%28sqrt%28a%2Fb%29%29%29%29)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin it was a typo, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your distance expression is off. Given symmetry, the distance between the two parallel normals is twice the distance from origin to either line. So, continue with 
$$ax\sec t -by\csc t=a^2-b^2$$
 to express the distance as

$$d(t)=\frac{2(a^2-b^2)}{\sqrt{ a^2\sec ^2t+b^2\csc^2 t}}\tag1$$

Set $d’(t)=0$ to get $\tan t= \pm\sqrt{\frac ba }$ and substitute into (1) to obtain the maximum distance

$$d_{max}= \frac{2(a^2-b^2)}{\sqrt{ a^2+b^2+2ab}}= 2(a-b)$$

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using parametric coordinates, one can express the normal to an ellipse in the slope for

For a given slope $m$, the normal to an ellipse can be expressed as

$$y = mx \pm \frac{m(a^2-b^2)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2m^2}}$$

Hence, for any slope, the distance can be expressed as

$$L(m) = \frac{d}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$

where $d = \frac{2m(a^2-b^2)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2m^2}}$

Hence

$$L(m) = (a^2-b^2). \frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2m^2}}$$

Comment: That’s fine, but I want to know why mine didn’t work, since $m^2=\frac ab $ is equivalent to $\tan^2 r =\frac ab$

Answer (score 1):

Okay, another try.
Given $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
and performing implicit differentiation we have
$$\frac{2x}{a^2}+\frac{2y'y}{b^2}=0$$
I won't consider a slope 'cause it may be equal to $\pm\infty$, instead a normal vector will be $$\left(\frac{x}{a^2},\frac{y}{b^2}\right)
\hbox{ or }(b^2x,a^2y)$$
with parametrization $x=a\cos t,\,y=a\sin t$ it will be $$(b\cos t,a\sin t)$$
Since the lines for parameters $t,r$ are collinear, we have cross product $=0$: $$(b\cos t)(a\sin r)-(b\cos r)(a\sin t)=0 \\ \sin(r-t)=0,\hbox{ so }\\r-t=\pi n$$
So the points will be $$(-a\cos r,-b\sin r),\,(a\cos r,b\sin r)$$
with the of difference $$(2a\cos r,2b\sin r)$$
[image]
and we have to dot multiply by the perpendicular to the normal vector and divide by its length to get the desired distance:
$$\begin{align*}\frac{|2(a\cos r,b\sin r).(-a\sin r,b\cos r)|}{\sqrt{(b\cos r,a\sin r)^2}}&=\frac{(a^2-b^2)|\sin(2r)|}{\sqrt{b^2\cos^2 r+a^2(1-\cos^2 r)}}\\
&=\frac{(a^2-b^2)|\sin(2r)|}{\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)\cos^2 r+a^2}}\\
&=\frac{(a^2-b^2)|\sin(2r)|}{\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)\frac{\cos(2r)+1}{2}+a^2}}
\end{align*}$$
so the formula for $L$ seems to correspond with OP's one.
Equating the derivative to $0$ we get
[$$2r=2\pi n-2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28abs%28sin%28x%29%29%2Fsqrt%28%28b%5E2-a%5E2%29*%28cos%28x%29%2B1%29%2F2%2Ba%5E2%29%29%27%3D0)
and substituting it back we have [$$\frac{2(a^2-b^2)}{a+b}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28abs%28sin%28-2*atan%28sqrt%28b%2Fa%29%29%29%29%2Fsqrt%28%28b%5E2-a%5E2%29*%28cos%28-2*atan%28sqrt%28b%2Fa%29%29%29%2B1%29%2F2%2Ba%5E2%29%29) so I'd suggest expanding the lines after finding the explicit formula for $L(r)$ so we can see if is there a mistake. Thanks.